# can not open vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

visual studio code...cannot open vs code....Unable to write program user data.......A system error occurred (EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\ ......Please make sure the following directories are writeable:

Answer (score 0):

Follow the path that you are installing the vsc, and on the directory, press right button

Open Properties

[image: Properties]

Disable Read Only and click apply and ok

[image]